# Find the $2\pi$-periodic $C^1$ function from the given Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Which $2\pi$-periodic $C^1$ function has the Fourier coefficients

$$
c_n = \begin{cases}
  ne^{-n}, & n\geq 0\\
  0, & n < 0 
\end{cases}
$$

The function that we want to find can be described as
$$
u(x) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{inx} = \sum_{0}^{\infty}ne^{-n}e^{inx} + \sum_{-\infty}^{0}0 = \sum_{0}^{\infty}ne^{-n}e^{inx}
$$
but not sure where to go from here. Help appreciated.

Comment: What is $\sum_1^\infty nt^n$?

Comment: It's $\frac{t}{(1-t)^2}$? But that also requires that t is less than 1 I think? Am I supposed to use that to find the function? I'm not entirely sure how.

Comment: We can further simply that to

$$u(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}n\,\left(e^{-1}\cdot e^{ix}\right)^n$$

Does the answer look clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n \left(e^{ix-1}\right)^n$$

Note that this series converges for every $x$ since $\left|e^{ix-1}\right| = \frac 1e < 1$.

To find to which values it converges to, you start from the series (valid for $|t | < 1$)

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n = \frac 1{1-t}$$
Differentiating wrt to $t$ both sides and multiplying by $t$, you get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nt^n = \frac t{(1-t)^2}$$

Now plug in $t = e^{ix-1}$ and you are done.